# DockerCompose Kong with Deck installed

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

I'm looking into using [Deck](https://docs.konghq.com/deck/overview/) for `Kong` to perform synchronized migration. However, I can't seem to find a way to install Deck cli into my `Kong` container using `docker-compose`.

Is there any guide/documentation I can follow to perform such an installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this can be resolved with docker container kong/deck if you will follow the below steps.

1. write `Dockerfile.deck` by using kong/deck image
   . write wait script for the 8001 (admin) port of kong.
   . kong/deck is just a container for the cli, so you should notice that its default `ENTRYPOINT` is deck command, so you should reset `ENTRYPOINT` if you want to run wait script.
   . copy `kong.yaml` from local to container directory
2. add your-deck service part to `docker-compose.yml` with build configuraiton of 1)
3. run dockercompose up after build

   This will work if you want to apply the `kong.yaml` at deployment time.

Comment: This is a little late but, it worked! Thanks for the help.